# TypeScript : Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to typescript. Basically I have a typescript GET function where I want to pass an ID to get that particular record back. I am getting this error on the return line. I researched this before posting here but could not get something close to my scenario. Help appreciated!

> Error TS2349  Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call
>   signature.

```
private getRecordRequestUrl = 'http://localhost/Service/api/ReservationRequest/GetRequestById';

 getRecordRequest(RequestId: number): Promise<ReservationModel[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.getRecordRequestUrl(RequestId))
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().Data as ReservationModel[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: `getRecordRequestUrl` is a string. You're trying to call it in `this.getRecordRequestUrl()`. Exactly the kind of mistake TypeScript is there to warn you about, which it does.

Answer (score 2):

`this.getRecordRequestUrl` is not a function, it's just a string. If you want to add `RequestId` to it, you should concatenate the value, e.g.: `return this.http.get(this.getRecordRequestUrl + '/' + RequestId)`

Answer (score 0):

getRecordRequestUrl is a string, and not a function

But in line `return this.http.get(this.getRecordRequestUrl(RequestId))` you call it like it would be a function.